# Stop download of streaming audio to HTML5 element with Buzz

Tags: html, html5-audio, buzz.js

I am using [Buzz](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/) to abstract HTML5 audio for internet radio.  This works well, but I need a way to stop downloading the stream when audio is stopped.

For example, when I start playing, I can see the network requests for the stream begin.  When I stop audio, that data for the stream is still being transferred, as if it were a static resource.  I need to either prevent that from happening, or get it to stop once audio is stopped.

I believe jPlayer does this by destroying the `<audio>` element, but I don't see any method for doing this in Buzz.  Is it possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time with the Buzz source, I don't see any method for doing this currently.  Fortunately, the raw audio element is exposed, allowing something like this:

```
buzz.sound.prototype.destroy = function () {
    this.set('src', '');
}
```

This probably messes up some internal state information for Buzz.  I'm looking into that right now.